# How can I see Facebook friend request message after accepting the request?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to see the personalized message associated with a friend request, after the request has been accepted? I can't find the message anywhere.

It's happened a few times that I accept a request using the top toolbar "Friend requests" feature, and notice only after accepting it, that the person had written something. Would be nice to see what it was.

Comment: I have the same question!  I received a friend request today that had a note about my daughter - the friend is traveling overseas with her.  I got really excited and clicked the "accept" button and now the message is gone :(   Is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Facebook topic](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=2318966938&topic=20922) it seems like there's no way of retrieving the message that was attached to the friend request.

As a last resort, if you have the original notification email still in your inbox, the message might be there?

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about looking for the email ... checking now, but it appears I don't get emails about it (my own notification settings). I think I'll re-enable these notifications.

Comment: Damn, the setting is uneditable for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the page of the user (who should be in your friends list by now) and just click the message button on the top right.